# Way too much resources are used with Pytorch

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, pytorch, htop

I am using pytorch to train a DQN model. With ubuntu, if I use htop, I get

[image]

As you can see, all resources are used and I am a bit worried about that.
Here is my [code](https://github.com/JeremieGauthier/AI_Exercices/blob/master/Atari_Breakout/DQN_Breakout.py).

Is there a way to use less resource? Do I have to add my requirement using pytorch?

Be aware that there's no GPUs on my machine, just CPUs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use [`torch.set_num_threads(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_num_threads) to specify the number of threads. Depending on the PyTorch version you use, maybe this function will not work correctly. See why in this [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16894). In there, you'll see that if needed you can use environment variables to limit OpenMP or MKL threads usage via `OMP_NUM_THREADS=?` and `MKL_NUM_THREADS=?` respectively, where `?` is the number of threads.

Keep in mind that these things are expected to run on GPUs with thousands of cores, so I would limit CPU usage only when extremely necessary.